# VBA Solidworks don't get print

Tags: vba, printing, solidworks

I'm trying to create a VBA code to print my drawings in SolidWorks. I've designed a UserForm with buttons, where each button corresponds to a sheet size (A4 Portrait and Landscape, A3, A2 and A1).

Please note that the drawing is already open and active. I want to use a shortcut to run my VBA code, and when I do, my UserForm should appear so I can choose my desired sheet size.

Below is my code; it doesn't show any errors, but it's not working. The code is for printing only in A4 sheet size; it works when I use it for other sheet sizes.

```
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swModelDocExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
Dim swPageSetup As SldWorks.PageSetup
Dim NameFile As String
Dim Printer As String 

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swModelDocExt = swModel.Extension
Set swPageSetup = swModel.PageSetup

NameFile = swModel.GetTitle

Printer = "Brother HL-5470DW series Printer" 

With swPageSetup
    .PrinterPaperSize = 9
    .Orientation = 1
    .HighQuality = True
    .Scale2 = False
    .DrawingColor = 1
End With

swModelDocExt.PrintOut4 Printer, NameFile, swPageSetup
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro that does it. In your code, third argument to PrintOut4 is wrong. It needs to be the PrintSpecification object

```
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModelDoc As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swModelDocExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
Dim swPageSetup As SldWorks.PageSetup
Dim swPrintSpec As SldWorks.PrintSpecification

Sub main()
Dim printerStr As String

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModelDoc = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swModelDocExt = swModelDoc.Extension
Set swPrintSpec = swModelDocExt.GetPrintSpecification

swPrintSpec.PrintToFile = False

printerStr = swPrintSpec.PrinterQueue ' Gets the default printer name, otherwise specify it yourself
nameFile = swModelDoc.GetTitle
swModelDocExt.PrintOut4 printerStr, nameFile, swPrintSpec

End Sub
```